# How do I get a sourced file in zshrc to run in bash?

Tags: bash, zsh, source

I have a bash script that includes a bunch of functions. I'd like this script to run using bash. The script has this at the top:

```
echo "BASH_VERSION""$BASH_VERSION"
echo "ZSH_VERSION""$ZSH_VERSION"
```

Currently I can see the script runs in ZSH.

How can I get the script to run using bash? I have `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top of the file but it still doesn't work. I'm using `source`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the script using `source`, then the commands in the script file will be executed by and in the *current* shell environment, no matter what the `#!`-line of the script says (that line is just a comment and will be ignored in this case). This is what `source` does.

If you run the script by giving the path and name of the script on the command line (e.g., `./myscript`), then, assuming the file is executable, it will be run by the interpreter mentioned in the `#!`-line at the very start of the script.  Function definitions and variables etc. in the file would be active for the duration of the script running, but would then be destroyed along with the rest of the script's environment when it terminates.

If the script file contains the definition of functions that you want to access in your current `zsh` shell environment, and if the functions in the file are written in a way that is compatible with the `zsh` shell, then sourcing it would be the appropriate thing to do.

If the functions are written explicitly for the `bash` shell (using `bash`-specific variables etc.), then you may want to write the rest of the application as a separate `bash` script and, from that script, source the file with the functions. Alternatively, you may want to rewrite the functions for the `zsh` shell, and then source the rewritten function definitions in a `zsh` shell.

Comment: `emulate ksh -c 'source ./that-file'` would enable the ksh emulation in `zsh` whilst interpreting code in the file. It would help as the bash language is closer to that of ksh than that of zsh.